# My Layout Handle carries through to all pages

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, event-observer

I've created a Layout Handle, which is updated by an observer. When the conditions are true (so that the handle is applied) that handle remains regardless of whether it should pass the test again.

My code is as follows

```
class Karl_CustomHandles_Model_Observer
{
public function addCustomHandles($observer){

    //Need + Works
    $update = Mage::getSingleton("core/layout")->getUpdate();
    $currentCategory = Mage::registry("current_category");

    if (!$currentCategory instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category) {
        return;
    }

    $defaultCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);
    $isChild = false;

    Mage::log($defaultCategory->getChildren() . " - excerpt end.");

    foreach(explode(",", $defaultCategory->getChildren()) as $child) {

        if ($child == $currentCategory->getId()) {
            $isChild = true;
        }

    }

    //Not works
    //Seems to apply the layouthandle to every page
    $allHandles = $update->getHandles();
    $update->resetHandles();

    if ($isChild == true) {
        foreach ($allHandles as $singleHandle){
            $update->addHandle($singleHandle);
        }
        $update->addHandle("child_is_true");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Bare in mind some of the code is a mess, attempting different solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually worked fine, the main issue was debugging in a phtml block - which was getting cached.